# lazy loading images on scroll and "come into view"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lazy-loading

I am using [Lazy](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) as a lazy image loading plugin. I have a div where I load divs like this:

```
<div class="nano-content" id="lScroll">

    /*... MORE LIKE THIS ... */
    <div class="card">
        <div class="city-selected city-medium clickChampion pointer"
     data-champ-id="1">
        <article>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="city">
                    CHAMPNAME
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
            <figure class="cFigure lazy" data-src="images/champions/CHAMPNAME_0.png"></figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    /*... MORE LIKE THIS ... */

</div>
```

So I initiate the plugin and it works for the first ones visible and when I scroll:

```
var $lazy = $('#lScroll .lazy');
if ($lazy.length) {
    $lazy.Lazy({
        appendScroll: $('#lScroll')
    });
}
```

But now I have a function that "filters" the divs by their attributes when I enter sth in my search input and it fails to load the image when the according div is shown:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#searchVod", function () {
    var $search = $(this);
    var $sVal = $search.val().toLowerCase();
    if ($sVal !== "") {
        $(".vodCard").hide();
        $('[data-champ*="' + $sVal + '"]').show();
        $('[data-role*="' + $sVal + '"]').show();
    } else {
        $(".vodCard").show();
    }
});
```

I tried `bind: "event"` /w and w/out `delay: 0` (loading the plugin in the search function) but when I searched it would load ALL images immediately in the background.

Any hint highly appreciated

UPDATE: I just noticed in Chrome DevTab after entering one letter in my searchbox it loads ALL the images and eventually the one I am searching for (if its the last it takes some time (30MB sth)

Comment: still learning how to use jsfiddle, but for now, have a look at the live site maybe? https://leaguestreams.net/vods/by-champion scroll a little, then enter "Zac" on the top... Edited my question though

Answer (score 6):

There is an excellent library called `Lozad.js` which can help you to make it easier to load your images like lazy load do but in easier way.

You can download it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lozad) from Github.

Demo page [here](https://apoorv.pro/lozad.js/demo/).

**Explanation:**
This library will load your images one by one on scrolling to each image anchor by class name.

**Example**

HTML:
At the header ->

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lozad"></script>
```

Image element should looks like this:

```
<img class="lozad" data-src="image.png">
```

Javascript

```
// Initialize library
lozad('.lozad', {
    load: function(el) {
        el.src = el.dataset.src;
        el.onload = function() {
            el.classList.add('fade')
        }
    }
}).observe()
```

Hope it will help you.
Best,
Ido.